# Microsoft Graph Toolkit React component is not re-rendering upon props state change

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api

I am utilizing Microsoft Graph Toolkit React component with templates as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/mgt-react). I added a react state as props to the component and the component is not re-rendering upon state change, as a normal React component would. Here is my code

```
import { Get } from '@microsoft/mgt-react'
import MailTemplate from './MailTemplate'
```

`` const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

 <Get resource={`/me/messages`} version='beta' scopes={['mail.read']} maxPages={1}>
    <MailTemplate template="value" count={count} />
</Get> ``

when count is updated, MailTemplate does not re-render with the updated values.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: set the `key` prop of the respective element to the stateful value. Although this is generally advised against, this will force the component to re-render. In your case: `key={count}`

```
<Get key={count} resource={`/me/messages`} version='beta' scopes={['mail.read']} maxPages={1}>
    <MailTemplate template="value" count={count} />
</Get>
```

I have the same issue and since I believe this is an actual bug, I submitted an issue in the MGT repo ([3144](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/3144)).

*(Would've posted this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so, sry)*